# How to implement an immutable IndexedSeq in Scala, backed by an Array

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to implement a tensor (multi-dimensional arrays) in a numerical processing library. The signature of the Tensor implementation is something as shown (cutting down on irrelevant parts of the signature):

```
final class Tensor[V](val data: Array[V], val shape: IndexedSeq[Int])
```

One of the concerns here is the performance of `IndexedSeq[Int]` (because they are backed by `scala.collection.Vector`). Being a numerical processing library, performance is a big concern here. I would like to swap out the default `Vector`-backed `IndexedSeq` with an `Array`-backed one.

I would like pointers as to what would be the best approach to do this (other than just reproducing the complete code for `IndexedSeq` from Scala collections and changing the relevant parts.) Thank you.

Comment: Do you have evidence that a `Vector` has worse performance than an `Array`?

Comment: @MikeAllen http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html : This blog post has decent evidence towards the same.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that before. I guess for lookups, etc. `Array` is way faster than `Vector`. It seems that you don't have too many options beyond manually implementing `IndexedSeq` using an `Array`. It appears that you only need to implement `apply` and `length`, so it shouldn't be too tough.

Comment: You worry about performance of the `Vector` in `shape`? How many entries does `shape` have? Even for convolutional neural networks for videos with three color channels it's something... I don't know... less than 32? Even if you have only 2 entries in each dimension, a 100-dimensional tensor with floats would already be >5GB large. Would the representation of `shape` really matter here?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin At first glance, I agree this can be seen as a case of premature optimization. But, in my defence, I chose the simplest case where I need to replace `IndexedSeq` in my code, to make my premise clear and short enough for an SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this suffice?

```
final class FastVector[+T](a: Array[T]) extends IndexedSeq[T] {
  override def apply(idx: Int) = a(idx)
  override def length = a.length
}
```

You would then use `FastVector` as your `IndexedSeq` type. All of the capabilities of an `IndexedSeq` are provided by the concrete methods of that trait, so `map`, `filter`, etc. are all available to you as well.

Comment: Why not just make the `shape` private in `Tensor` itself?

Comment: I'd actually consider specializing to `Array[Int]` if you only need it and guarantee there is no boxing there. Also, extend `IndexedSeqOptimized` not `IndexedSeq` directly.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I guess because it's not private in the OP's signature. It looks like `shape` needs to be publicly visible.

Comment: On further thought, this way you get boxing/unboxing when calling the methods because `IndexedSeq` itself isn't specialized. They should be mostly inlined by JIT, though...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Can you elaborate a bit more on 'boxing/unboxing' issues? Do you mean I will face them even if I specialize on `Int` ?

Comment: @suj1th I'm not sure whether this will be an issue in practice. The class I've proposed is simply a wrapper for an `Array`, so it doesn't do any boxing/unboxing if all you're doing is retrieving values from class instances.

Comment: @MikeAllen Thank you. I think, given the constraints of the problem, your solution fits my purpose best. And yes, I only intend to retrieve values from the class instances of `FastVector`. Cheers!

Comment: @suj1th Just one word of caution: if the wrapped array is accessible elsewhere, it's possible for its contents to be modified outside of the protection afforded by the wrapper. You can ensure that's not the case by writing factory methods that copy or create their own arrays.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you can do two things:

1. don't make the `data` field public (i.e. val), so that outside code cannot access it
2. construct the `data` Array your-self, i.e in the constructor of Tensor,  so that there isn't any ref to the array outside of the Tensor instance

Eg:

```
class Tensor[V] private (data: Array[V], shape: Array[Int])

object Tensor{
  def vector[V](input: Seq[V]) = new Tensor(input.toArray, Array(1))
  def matrix[V](input: Seq[V], w: Int, h: Int) = new Tensor(input.toArray, Array(w,h))
}

// example use
Tensor.vector(1 to 20)
Tensor.matrix(1 to 20, 5, 4)
```

---

<s>Also, in general there exist a wrapper around Array that is an IndexedSeq: WrappedArray. You can do it such as: `val iSeq: IndexedSeq[Int] = Array(42)` and Scala will automatically wrap the Array into a WrappedArray.</s>

Comment: `WrappedArray` is mutable.

Comment: ;-) Yeah, unfortunate, because an immutable `WrappedArray` is exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Juh_ Sadly, I do not have control over the signature of the constructors. So, I cannot make `data` private.

Comment: @MikeAllen I agree "immutable `WrappedArray`" is a better way to state what I am looking for :)